# Mapping VW DTCs from a scantool to the raw data obtained

Tags: engine, vw, obd-ii, can-bus, scan-tool

I scanned a VW Golf TDI 2015 using a scantool (at a workshop) and it gave the following 2 codes -

> Engine module: P0103 - Mass Air Flow (MAF) (G70): Signal too High
>
> Instrument cluster module: B103E - Fuel Level Sensor 1: Short to Plus

Then I hooked my laptop (PuTTY and elm327) to read the raw data and got the following data -

> For engine:  Sent: 19 02 04 Reply: 7E8075902FF001CA4AF
>
> For Instrument cluster: Sent: 19 02 04 Reply: 77E07590299903E1208

Can someone please help me find out how can I arrive to the fault codes from the corresponding raw data. I can find out the faults myself instead of going to the workshop.

Comment: Why not just use a program lik [OBD Auto Doctor](https://www.obdautodoctor.com/download). This is just an example ... there are others. There is free software out there ... why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I have tried OBD doctor but it didn't give any DTCs. Maybe it reads mode 03, 07 (basic OBD commands) only

Comment: There are other options out there.

Comment: yeah I tried the free ones, neither one reads other than engine.

Answer (score 0):

77E07590299903E1208 it`s 
77E - adress ecu |
 07 - number of bytes |
 59 - positive answer from ecu |
 02 -reportDTCbyStatusMask
 99
upper bytes from ISO 14229

90 3E 12 - need to divide byte 90 how to "9" and "0", after "9" will change to "B1" and result: B103E 12 ,

also you can find how 903E12xh -- 9453074 number of DTC in list VAG.

08 - Status Mask describe in to ISO 14229

Comment: I get this, but according to your decoding, the engine should give P001C. However the code thrown by the tool was P0103. There is the actual confusion.

Comment: Hello, Soumya Sen!

Comment: Hello, Soumya Sen! Little bit not correct ) .It is UDS we must ose 3 bytes. 7E8 07 59 02 FF 00 1C A4 AF --  00 1C A4  and decoding in to dec 7332 after this operation need to find VAG DTC List and only for Engine ECU. How can you note P0103 OBD DTC, but I think VAG use self rule for more information. IMHO. Sorry for my English %)

Comment: ok so I searched 7332 on google and it gave P0103 DTC for VW. So basically I need to convert from hex to dec value. But is there a mapping from the decimal value to the P codes for VW? I can't find such a mapping on the internet.

Comment: Yes of case ! The same DTC P0103 will be dec 16487 or  Hex 4067 or  Bin 01 00 0000 0110 0111  http://www.aficionadosalamecanica.net/manuales/Vag-codes.pdf  but not so full list, please see!

Comment: thanks for the list. But how is it dec 16487? As we discussed earlier, it is dec 7332, right?

Comment: Ok, 16487 Dec also item in VAG DTC list :-), also for EOBD P0103 will be  0103 hex, after decoding in to Dec 259. 259 also item from list :-)  It is fucking VAG )))) In result we have following items: DTC P0103  for OBD standard 01 03 (Bin 00 00 0001 0000 011) for VAG in DEC 00259 (HEX 0103), 07332 (HEX 1CA4), 16487 (HEX 4067)